Custom permalink for 'post' not working
I want to set custom permalink for (standard) post and have url structure, like

site.com/guide/news/ - blog list (or archive) page
site.com/guide/news/post-name - for single post

My steps:

I have a blog page second level, like site.com/guide/news/. that is, I have page guide and child page news
I set permalink structure for post, like guide/news/%postname%/
Clear permalink buffer

And now I have:

Page site.com/guide/news/ as blog list;
each posts have a link like site.com/guide/news/post-name
After click on post link I get reload site.com/guide/news

And this is the problem, it seems that all the links are correct, but when you click, the link does not go to the address.
I also have several custom post types, such as events.
Everything is simple with them, assign the argument
'has_archive' = 'guide/events', 
'rewrite' = array
, 'slug' = 'guide/events',
  'with_front' = false

and everything works fine and the list of events and each event is reflected in the correct URL,
but standard posts behave somehow differently!
Please, help me!
SOLVED!
after looking closely at setting up permalinks, I noticed that I had the / in front.
those. was /guide/news/%postname%/
but you need guide/news/%postname%/
After making the changes, all links began to work correctly.

have you tested this in a rewrite rule analyser plugin to see which rewrite rule it thinks matches this best?

Follow these steps:

Flush Permalinks: Go to Settings > Permalinks and hit "Save Changes" to flush rewrite rules.
Check Conflicts: Ensure no plugins or custom codes conflict with your permalink settings.
Adjust .htaccess: Add this to your .htaccess file.

RewriteRule ^guide/news/(.+)/?$ index.php?name=$1 [L]
These steps should help resolve the issue with your post URLs.

in a worst case scenario the htaccess change might result in a redirect loop as WP spots the URL and tries to redirect back to what it considers to be the "canonical" URL

Thanks for help and idea with rewriterule

Here are two ways to fix this:

Use a Prefix for Single Posts:

Modify your permalink structure for posts to include a prefix specifically for single posts. For example:
guide/news/post/%postname%/
This way, single post URLs will look like site.com/guide/news/post/your-post-name/ and won't match the blog list page pattern.

Use a Separate Permalink Structure for the Blog List:

Create a separate permalink structure specifically for the blog list page. For example:
Posts: guide/news/%postname%/ (individual posts)
Blog List: guide/news/ (displays all posts)
You can achieve this by creating a custom page template for your blog list and assigning a different permalink structure to that page template.
Here are some additional tips:
After making changes to your permalink structure, remember to save your changes and flush the rewrite rules. This ensures WordPress updates its internal routing based on your new structure. Go to Settings > Permalinks and click "Save Changes" even if you didn't modify the default settings.
If you're using custom post types like "events" and their permalinks work correctly, it suggests there might be a specific issue with the default post permalink structure. Using a prefix for single posts is a common and effective solution.
